# How can change the size of the block depending of its content in css?

Tags: html, css, height, size, width

I would like to create a box, that can change its width and height depending on the length of its content. So if it has just one line it it, it should have a smaller height. If it has 10 lines, it should have a bigger height. I would also like to have the box centered. Thank you in advance. I have this code already:

```
<div style=" border: 1px solid black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; max-height: 25em; max-width: 20em; min-height: 10em; min-width: 12em; position: relative; white-space: nowrap">
<img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-4wmRO867-W4/V7qwJGfVBYI/AAAAAAAAAL0/XQHdOxK34asRSXt3FfBKnOS_wGRcneFEwCEw/s1600/quote_basic.png" style="border: none; clear: left; float: left; position: relative;" />
<span style="font-style: italic; left: 50%; margin-right: -50%; margin: 0; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50% , -50%); display: inline-block;"> "This is the one-line content" </span>
<img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-kg4kc90TSqs/V7rjthACJLI/AAAAAAAAAMM/sV7buqkUWH8KqYfBVlCGnq14qMdo4eetwCLcB/s1600/quote_basic_mirrored.png" style="border: none; clear: right; float: right;position: relative; top: 8em" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to create a box, that can change its width and height depending on the length of its content.

`display:inline-block` will do most of this. the only caveat is the the box will keep getting wider until it reaches 100% width of it's parent.

The only way to force breaking of the text before then is to apply either a `width` or `max-width`

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
blockquote {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
  font-family: Lobster;
}
blockquote:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "\201C";
}
blockquote:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: .0;
  content: "\201D";
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<blockquote>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, repellat.</span>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</span>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
</blockquote>
```

As for the centering. there are **multiple** techniques depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this:

I stripped down all inline css:

```
<div>
<img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-4wmRO867-W4/V7qwJGfVBYI/AAAAAAAAAL0/XQHdOxK34asRSXt3FfBKnOS_wGRcneFEwCEw/s1600/quote_basic.png"/>
<p> "This is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line contentThis is the one-line content" </p>
<img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-kg4kc90TSqs/V7rjthACJLI/AAAAAAAAAMM/sV7buqkUWH8KqYfBVlCGnq14qMdo4eetwCLcB/s1600/quote_basic_mirrored.png"/>
</div>

div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

p {
    padding: 40px;
}

div img:nth-of-type(1) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div img:nth-of-type(2) {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And here is a little video of the result: http://screencast.com/t/cSyF3mkvTS